# Null bytes when using xlwt to make valid excel file

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding, xlwt

I'm using Python 2.7 and attempting to automate downloading an excel file from a website using the mechanize library. I used CharDet to discover the original encoding for the file, which is "iso-8859-2".  In order to properly separate the data into columns based on the data read by mechanize, I have an intermediary step storing the data to a text file.

```
fileobj = open("data.txt", 'wb')
fileobj.write(response.read())
fileobj.close()
```

To create the Excel file, I am using the xlwt module.

```
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding  = "utf-8")
sheet = book.add_sheet('sheet1')
```

After this, I read through the text file and attempt to decode the text and encode it into utf-8 form with

```
for line in fileobj:
    line = line.decode("iso-8859-2").encode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

The problem is that attempting to iterate over the file using Python's csv default reader reports an error that there are null bytes.  Placing the encoded text in a .txt file shows there are no null bytes in the lines themselves, so I am not sure where the problem is coming from.

Comment: If you're still having the problem, could you share a piece of data.txt so we can try to reproduce the problem ? (if the problem has been fixed, can you share your solution ?)